# Win 2019 + SQL Server 2014 slowly locks up the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, aws, windows-server

We have a 2019 + 2014 sql server box that was running fine for a few days after we first stood it up on Ec2.

After a week I removed a temp drive (EBS) that we had initially used to load up the databases for importing. DBs are on D and logs on E. We imported the databases from the F drive (our temp drive).

Since I removed the EBS volume (F) the server has slowly started locking up and I have to force stop it through the AWS console. I can't RDP, it stops responding to DB requests, etc. This process takes around 4 hours after boot before it becomes unusable.

There's nothing crazy in the Event Viewer. There are a bunch of 17187 and 17897 Error Level events from MSSQLSERVER:

> SQL Server is not ready to accept new client connections. Wait a few
>   minutes before trying again. If you have access to the error log, look
>   for the informational message that indicates that SQL Server is ready
>   before trying to connect again.  [CLIENT: 10.33.1.2]

and

> SQL Server is not ready to accept new client connections. Wait a few
>   minutes before trying again. If you have access to the error log, look
>   for the informational message that indicates that SQL Server is ready
>   before trying to connect again.  [CLIENT: 10.33.1.2]

Those are because the PHP instance connecting to it is using an older version of the MSSQL driver to connect. The data shows up on the app it just throws those errors. It shouldn't lock up the entire server.

The only thing I can think of: Does MSSQL need access to the initial drive a db was imported from for some reason?

I'm baffled.

Comment: Is this problem reproducible? (IE Can you spin up a new VM and get the same issue?) If not I'd suggest a tear-down and rebuild may be faster than figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Did you detach or drop the database on F: prior to removing the drive?  Use Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if anything is trying to access files on F:\

Comment: I did not. I just removed it from Ec2 and it removed itself from disk manager.

So far nothing is showing up from MSSQL looking at F or G (I added two temp drives since I couldn't remember if I restored the original DBs from F or G)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/itc9dsgd65q3bke/Screenshot%202019-07-29%2013.31.32.png?dl=0

Comment: I haven't tried to reproduce it. The databases are huge and it would take us all weekend to migrate them again. That will be my last option this weekend if I can't get to the bottom of it.